# Integration of probabilities

Tags: integration

I am trying to find a way to properly formulate a specific integral.

Given two probabilities:
$$
f(x(0))=\begin{cases}
  1/2,  & -1\le x(0) \le 1\\
  0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f(x(1)|x(0))=\begin{cases}
  1/2,  & x(0)-1\le x(1) \le x(0)+1\\
  0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
I want to compute the integral:
$$
\int_{x(0)} f(x(0))*f(x(1)\vert x(0))\,dx(0)
$$
I know what the result will be, since one can deduce it by drawing those two. But I cannot figure out how to split the intervals up and reformulate the integration limits correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not convolving the densities. The integral you presented is an application of the following theorem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalProbabilityTheorem.html

In your case the summation step over the events partitioning the sample space is what leads to the integral and the formula for finding the density may be recovered by differentiating the final result, which is the probability density of X1.

As for your integral, try the following:

- What is the maximum value for x1 s.t. the result is not zero?
- What is the minimal value for x1 s.t. the result is not zero?
- How does the integral behave for values of x1 that are between those bounds?
- Sanity check: Does the density of x1 integrated give you 1?

If you have any further questions don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: I know that it is about the total probability theorem for continuous pdf's, but thought that the integral was a convolution, which is completely wrong..

Comment: Precisely. Your presented solution outline is correct.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help! I sometimes oversee a lot by not approaching a problem( in this case just a subproblem) systematically.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Range of $x(1)$ is : $ -2 \le x(1) \le 2$

We split this into two cases:

- first the case : $-2 \le x(1) \le 0$ . The range of $x(0)$ has then to be : $-1 \le x(0) \le 1+x(1)$
- second the case : $0 \le x(1) \le 2$ . The range of $x(0)$ has then to be : $x(1)-1 \le x(0) \le 1$

Then simply integrate $1/4$ over these two intervals in order to obtain the pdf of $f(x(1))$